# Google map is not working on emulator and mobile device in ionic

Tags: cordova, google-maps, geolocation, ionic-framework

I have implemented simple ionic application with google map using following tutorials
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrvJog)
and [nraboy](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/) both are working fine in browser and in `ionic lab` when i serve the ioni application using `ionic serve` command. But when i build the application and run it in the emulator or in mobile device map is not visible neither it display any error. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three points, you should know:

1. Use a map plugin, like this one: https://github.com/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps It is much faster, then the javascript solution and you have less traffic. The plugin is using vectors.
2. You have to whitelisten the Google urls in your app.
3. You have to register your app on https://developers.google.com/